# "&" And "And" In A Prepared Statement Failing

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have this chunk of PHP code (abridged for brevity) as a prepared statement that allows the user to search through a database using a series title...

```
$series = null;
if (isset($_GET["series"])) $series = $_GET["series"];

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=Radio", "", "");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if (isset($series)) {
        $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM dbo.Schedule
            WHERE dbo.Schedule.Series LIKE :series
            ORDER BY dbo.Schedule.Date ASC";
    }
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    if (isset($series)) {
        $stmt->execute(array(":series" => $series));
    }
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

It works perfectly fine for any series title that DOES NOT include &, but it fails (produces no results) for any series title that does.

For instance, Abounding Ability works but Receiving & Ministering Healing does not (even though both are in the Series field of the database.

I tried `htmlspecialchars(rawurlencode($_GET["series"]))` and each one individually.

On the SQL server, passing the same query (using the title) works just fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Radio].[dbo].[Schedule]
where Series like 'Receiving & Ministering Healing'
```

My guess is that the problem is in the execution of the prepared statement or in binding the parameters.

I did a search on [PHP's Prepared Statements page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for &, but didn't see any results.

**Edit:**

I used this to get it working...

```
$series = null;
if (isset($_GET["series"])) $series = $_GET["series"];
$queries = parse_url($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
if (substr($queries["path"], 7) == "Receiving%20&%20Ministering%20Healing") $series = "Receiving & Ministering Healing";
```

I'm sure it's a terrible way to do it, but no other option was working.  Of course, that only works in this particular case.  I welcome a better solution.

**Edit 2:**

I found that a series with the WORD And in it (Graces And Places) presents the same issue.  I ended up duplicating my "fix" for Receiving & Ministering Healing for it.

I doesn't seem to have anything to do with the URL query (or the word And wouldn't matter), but the prepared statement.

Comment: Look at the actual query that gets executed (ie: `PDO::queryString`). You'll see it's not what you think it is, because `&` has special meaning in URLs, so `$_GET['series']` is not what you'd expect.

Comment: Please `var_dump($_GET)`. I suspect you're creating an `<a>` tag manually and you don't encode `&`.

Comment: `http://www.flcbranson.org/api/radio/?series=Receiving & Ministering Healing` (typed into the address bar of my web browser) is the address in question.  I'm not trying to link anything, at the moment (at that point, I would 'htmlentities()' as mentioned).  But `&amp;` wouldn't be successful in the query `SELECT * FROM [Radio].[dbo].[Schedule] where Series like 'Receiving &amp; Ministering Healing'`, so I don't see that being an option.

Comment: `&amp;` is an HTML entity. You need `%26` for URLs!

Comment: @doubleJ The htmlentities is needed when you write the result into HTML, not when assembling the query string...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I didn't know about %26.  Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be multiple causes for this. The `&` character is evil on multiple levels, in this case, these two seem relevant:

It can be that your request looks like this (`&` signs highlighted under)

```
http://somedomain.com/somepage.php?param=something&series=Receiving & Ministering Healing
                                                  ^ (valid)         ^ (unintended!)
```

because the title is not escaped for URLs. This would mean that the & character marks a new parameter name - and would truncate the `series` to be `Receiving` instead of the full title `Receiving & Ministering`, resulting in the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Radio].[dbo].[Schedule]
where Series like 'Receiving '
```

**You should probably show us how you assemble the URL for the request** to be able to recommend more approporiate solution, but you should use **[urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)** for escaping values to be used in GET parameters.

Or the problem could be (however it is not this case now) that you are **writing** the values wrongly.

A single `&` character is not valid in HTML! The correct escaping is `&amp;`

You should HTML encode the output from the **SELECT** queries with [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo "<h1>".htmlentities($resultComingFromQuery)."</h1>";
```

**EDIT**

A bad request will likely result in a bad response (GIGO)... This:

```
http://www.flcbranson.org/api/radio/?series=Receiving%20%26%20Ministering Healing
```

is the proper request. This is **URL encoded**. You have to decode it:

```
$decodedTitle = urldecode($_GET['series']);
```

And use that in the query...

Comment: The OP says the query is returning no results, so it's the first problem.

Comment: As mentioned, I tried `htmlspecialchars()` and `rawurlencode()`.  I just tested `urlencode()` and `htmlentities()` and neither produced results.

Comment: @doubleJ **your request is bad** try this:`http://www.flcbranson.org/api/radio/?series=Receiving%20%26%20Ministering Healing`, **and** use `urldecode($_GET['series'])` in the code to decode it.

Comment: Ok, so `http://www.flcbranson.org/api/radio/?series=Receiving%20%26%20Ministering Healing` gives results, as expected.  Unfortunately, that isn't helping me as the user should be able to type `http://www.flcbranson.org/api/radio/?series=Receiving & Ministering Healing`.  Is there a way to allow it?  I'm guessing that you're correct in that it's viewing the address as two separate queries.  Maybe I could `if (second variable) variable1 + variable2` (I know that syntax is all wrong, but you get the point).

Comment: @doubleJ Sadly, it is not possible... But I think it is very inconvenient to type this kind of stuff into the browser - so I'd suggest a simple HTML form, with a single text field, that would pu this together...

Comment: That's true.  Technically, this is an API that I'm making calls to.  It's my API, so I can do whatever needs to be done to get it to work.